# In jquery run time dynamic value not able to get it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating the complete syntax of jquery and assigning it in the PHP field and on the button click I get the field value but the problem is in jquery the syntax I used to replace their value is not replaced. It shows the same variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ajaxUrl" id="ajaxUrl" value="'index.php?mode=ajax&action=modHistory&process=save&account={$account}&date=' + uenc(readNextdate('dateField')) + '&response=' + uenc(fieldVal('response')) + '&contact=' + uenc(fieldVal('contact')) + '&salesman=' + uenc(fieldVal('salesman')) + '&activity=' + uenc(fieldVal('activity')) + '&project=' + uenc(fieldVal('project')) + '&owner=' + uenc(fieldVal('owner')) + '&status=' + uenc(fieldVal('modstatus')) + '&product=' + uenc(fieldVal('product')) + '&duration=' + uenc(fieldVal('duration')) + '&username=' + uenc(fieldVal('username')) + '&oldProduct=' + uenc(fieldVal('oldProduct')) + '&oldDuration=' + uenc(fieldVal('oldDuration')) + '&oldActivity=' + uenc(fieldVal('oldActivity')) + '&oldDate={$pointer}{$save}&extraId={$extraId}&time=' + new Date().getTime() + '&token={$XSRFToken|escape:'url'}'">
```

At the jquery end I suppose it will replace the jquery syntax with there value but it shows the same value -

'index.php?mode=ajax&action=modHistory&process=save&account=10002&date=' + uenc(readNextdate('dateField')) + '&response=' + uenc(fieldVal('response')) + '&contact=' + uenc(fieldVal('contact')) + '&salesman=' + uenc(fieldVal('salesman')) + '&activity=' + uenc(fieldVal('activity')) + '&project=' + uenc(fieldVal('project')) + '&owner=' + uenc(fieldVal('owner')) + '&status=' + uenc(fieldVal('modstatus')) + '&product=' + uenc(fieldVal('product')) + '&duration=' + uenc(fieldVal('duration')) + '&username=' + uenc(fieldVal('username')) + '&oldProduct=' + uenc(fieldVal('oldProduct')) + '&oldDuration=' + uenc(fieldVal('oldDuration')) + '&oldActivity=' + uenc(fieldVal('oldActivity')) + '&oldDate=1638172792&FIELD1='+uenc(readNextdate('mod-RCMANL-ANAL01'))+'&ADDN-FIELD1=RCMANL-ANAL01&FIELD2='+uenc(jqfieldVal('.RCMANL-ANAL15 select'))+'&ADDN-FIELD2=RCMANL-ANAL15&FIELD3='+uenc(jqfieldVal('.RCMANL-ANAL13 input'))+'&ADDN-FIELD3=RCMANL-ANAL13&FIELD4='+uenc(readNextdate('mod-RCMANL-ANAL51'))+'&ADDN-FIELD4=RCMANL-ANAL51&FIELD5='+uenc(readNextdate('mod-RCMANL-ANAL80'))+'&ADDN-FIELD5=RCMANL-ANAL80&extraId=&time=' + new Date().getTime() + '&token=2d62814f617129a0a611dd505ec239a2'

Comment: Are all these bits like `uenc(readNextdate('dateField'))` supposed to be JavaScript code? All you've done is put a string inside a hidden field. There's no context here in which that code would be executed.

Comment: @ADyson When I am using the same code in the js file it workes fine in it the only thing is when I am getting from the PHP file it does not work.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "using in the JS file". How exactly did you "use" it? we'd need to see the context. PHP isn't really relevant here either, you're trying to use it in some HTML which doesn't make sense. You can't execute JS inside HTML (with the exception of inline event handlers, which this isn't). And why are you putting a URL in a hidden field too? that also seems odd but perhaps there's a sensible reason for it.

Comment: If you want to execute this code you need to handle the button click event you mentioned, execute the code and then assign the result to the hidden field